# Find out if youtube video is GEMA protected

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am looking to find out wether a video on youtube is blocked (in germany) because its GEMA protected. Ideally via the youtube API.
I would like to know if its protected before the player tells me so.
An example for an video which is GEMA protected (the protection only occurs with german ip): 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgfcToAjfdc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check this in an HTTP request by using search.list and specifying `part=contentDetails`. contentDetails has a [blocked](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.regionRestriction.blocked[]) section that gives you the region code of any countries where the video is blocked.

For example, for this video, you would call:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=BgfcToAjfdc&key=[API_KEY]

And you get:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/wC5hYBNHuSGatyO7FsTaHrWY5HI\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/4dW1h00OUpXXhtaz2M71v9cXGsQ\"",
   "id": "BgfcToAjfdc",
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT5M26S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": false,
    "regionRestriction": {
     "blocked": [
      "DE"
     ]
```

You can see in the `blocked` section that the video is blocked in Germany.

Comment: thats exactly what i was looking for. thank you very much.

Comment: to complete this: INSTEAD of a blocked section, there might also appear an allowed section. makes sense e.g. if a vid is blocked in all countries but one: 


"regionRestriction": {
     "allowed": [
      "DE"
     ]
}